# How can I use the same route for multiple functions in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm currently using `python3` and `Flask`; I have two functions defined using the same route. - How can I get `index2` to print.

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if request.authorization and request.authorization.username == 'user1' and request.authorization.password == 'pass1':
        return '<h1>You are logged in</h1>'
    return make_response('Could not verify!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

@app.route('/')
def index2():
    print('In Index 2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Both functions share the same app.route. Give the index2 function a different app route and call it from index function

Comment: how to call index2() from index()?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have multiple options; one of which is to call `index2` function from within the `index` function:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if request.authorization.username == 'user1' and request.authorization.password == 'pass1':
        index2() # you can return index2() if that's the logged in page.
        return '<h1>You are logged in</h1>'

    return make_response('Could not verify!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})


def index2():
    print('In Index2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The second option is to differ both functions based on the http method being called:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if request.authorization.username == 'user1' and request.authorization.password == 'pass1':
        return '<h1>You are logged in</h1>'

    return make_response('Could not verify!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def save():
    print('Save operations here')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The third option is to use different parameters:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if request.authorization.username == 'user1' and request.authorization.password == 'pass1':
        return '<h1>You are logged in</h1>'

    return make_response('Could not verify!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

@app.route('/<string:page_name>')
def index2(page_name):
    print(f"{page_name}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To call index2, try the following quick and dirty code. I'm sure you can improve to have it fit your needs.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if request.authorization and request.authorization.username == 'user1' and request.authorization.password == 'pass1':
        return '<h1>You are logged in</h1> <a href="{{ url_for('index2') }}">Click me to go to index2</a>'

    return make_response('Could not verify!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

@app.route('/index2')
def index2():
    print ('In Index2')
```

Comment: Why do you create a new app.route? As far as I know you don't need to do that.