# Flask Load New Page After Streaming Data

Tags: python, html, flask, web-applications, httpresponse

I have simple Flask App that takes a CSV upload, makes some changes, and streams the results back to the user's download folder as CSV.

HTML Form

```
<form action = {{uploader_page}} method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <label>CSV file</label><br>
    <input type = "file" name = "input_file" required></input><br><br>
    <!-- some other inputs -->
    <div id = "submit_btn_container">
        <input id="submit_btn" onclick = "this.form.submit(); this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Processing';" type = "submit"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

PYTHON

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response, redirect, flash, render_template
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['POST'])
def uploadFile():
    uploaded_file = request.files['input_file']
    data_df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(uploaded_file.read()))
    # do stuff
    
    # stream the pandas df as a csv to the user download folder
    return Response(data_df.to_csv(index = False),
                            mimetype = "text/csv",
                            headers = {"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=result.csv"})
```

This works great and I see the file in my downloads folder.

However, I'd like to display "*Download Complete*" page after it finishes.

How can I do this? Normally I use `return redirect("some_url")` to change pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using [`send_file()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.send_file) or [`send_from_directory()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory) for sending files.

Getting 2 responses from 1 request is not possible, but you can split the problem into chunks with the help of some JS, following this simple diagram (not very UML precise, but that's it):

*this diagram refers to a previous and simpler version of the code, which was later updated after the OP asked for `flash()` to be called*

[image]

1. POST to `/uploader` through a function called from the form by `onsubmit`, so that besides saving the file you can also have some logic there, like checking the response status
2. process the file (I did a mockup of your processing through `upper()`)
3. if the server responds with `201` ("Created") then you can save the file and print "*Download Complete*" (I used `window.document.body.innerHTML` because it's only one tag and we can replace all the previous DOM; it shouldn't be used to change complex HTML)
4. else, if the server responds with other status codes (like `500`), POST to `/something-went-wrong` to get the new - possibly flashed - HTML to be rendered. The POST step is not shown in the diagram.

To test the error page, make some syntax error in the processing inside `upload_file()`, like `data_df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(uploaded_file.`**aread()**`))`

In the `something-went-wrong` response I addeed a CSP header to mitigate a possible malicious attack, because we can't trust the user enough.

Here's the code:

**main.py**

```
from flask import (Flask,
                   request,
                   redirect,
                   render_template,
                   send_file,
                   url_for,
                   Response, jsonify, flash, make_response)
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "your_secret"

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/uploader", methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    try:
        uploaded_file = request.files['input_file']
        data_df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(uploaded_file.read()))

        # do stuff
        data_df["foo"] = data_df["foo"].str.upper()

        # Stream buffer:
        io_buffer = BytesIO()
        data_df.to_csv(io_buffer)
        io_buffer.seek(0)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)  # and log if needed
        # Here I return the exception string just as an example! Not good in real usage.
        return jsonify({"message": str(ex)}), 500
    else:
        return send_file(io_buffer,
                         download_name="result.csv",
                         as_attachment=True), 201


@app.route("/something-went-wrong", methods=["POST"])
def something_went_wrong():
    flash(request.get_json()["message"])
    response = make_response(render_template("something-went-wrong.html"), 200)
    response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "default-src 'self'"
    return response
```

**The form with the JS handler**:

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return submitHandler()">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <label>CSV file</label><br>
    <input type="file" id="inputFile" name="input_file" required/><br><br>
    <!-- some other inputs -->
    <div id="submitBtnContainer">
        <input id="submitBtn" type="submit"/>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function submitHandler() {
        const csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

        let formData = new FormData();
        const file = document.getElementById('inputFile').files[0];
        formData.append("input_file", file);

        fetch("/uploader", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": csrf_token,
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status != 201) {
                response.json().then(data => {
                    fetch("/something-went-wrong", {
                        method: "POST",
                        body: JSON.stringify({"message": data["message"]}),
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                            "X-CSRFToken": csrf_token,
                        },
                    })
                    .then(response => response.text())
                    .then(text => {
                        window.document.body.innerHTML = text;
                    })
                });
            }
            else {
                return response.blob().then(blob => {
                    const file = new Blob([blob], { type: 'text/csv' });
                    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    let fileLink = document.createElement('a');
                    fileLink.href = fileURL;
                    fileLink.download = "result.csv";
                    fileLink.click();
                    window.document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Download Complete</h1>";
                });
            }
        })
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

For completeness, my dummy csv `"file.csv"`:

| foo |
| --- |
| bar |

Comment: Works great! I ended up using "var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("blur_form")) to pass all the form data in, but other than that this worked as intended.

Comment: I'm wondering how do you pass error information using this approach? Previously I use "flash(some_error) return redirect(same_page)", but now since the xhr.onreadystatechange function is handling the request and redirecting, my flash messages don't show up.

Comment: You can do it various ways. I edited my answer to show you one way with the help of some subsequent POSTs: I use them to carry a message (see the value returned from the except block in `upload_file()`) that will be evenutally flashed. I also preferred to switch from AJAX to the `fetch` API for doing all of that, and I render "Download Complete" directly with JS, without using a Flask route.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some changes.

set `window.open('')` in input onclick event.

HTML Form

```
<form action ="/uploader" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        <label>CSV file</label><br>
        <input type = "file" name = "input_file" required></input><br><br>
        <!-- some other inputs -->
        <div id = "submit_btn_container">
            <input id="submit_btn" onclick = "this.form.submit(); this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Processing'; window.open('your_url');" type = "submit"></input>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This opens a new tab with the page when I tried it. Is it possible to redirect the current page?

Comment: you are returning a file to user. if you redirect user on same page , user did not get file.

Answer (score 0):

You need two functions, one to deal with the processing such as uploadFile(), and another in the same app route to return render template.

When the uploadFile() function is completed: `completed = True`

Then, code another function which tests the global variable `if completed:` to return render template.

See: [How can I use the same route for multiple functions in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811041/how-can-i-use-the-same-route-for-multiple-functions-in-flask)

Finally, return a variable to the page with Jinja2 and use Javascript to identify if that variable exists to load your 'download completed' page by Javascript.

Python:

```
    from flask import Flask, request, Response, redirect, flash, render_template
    from io import BytesIO
    import pandas as pd

    completed = False
    
    @app.route('/uploader', methods = ['POST'])
    def uploadFile():
        uploaded_file = request.files['input_file']
        data_df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(uploaded_file.read()))
        # do stuff
        # When stuff is done
        global completed
        completed = True
        # stream the pandas df as a csv to the user download folder
        return Response(data_df.to_csv(index = False),
                                mimetype = "text/csv",
                                headers = {"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=result.csv"})
```

How to load a new page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-can-a-page-be-forced-to-load-another-page-in-javascript/

Javascript conditionals: https://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/conditional-operators-if.html

Using Jinja2 to render a variable: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/

Also, you should really wrap your uploadFile() function with try and except to catch upload errors.